# djangoのviews.pyの中でjoinが何をしているのか

Tags: python, sql, django

素人質問で恐縮ですが、下記コード中の

```
output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
```

部分が何をしているのかわかりません。「「,」で区切って`question_text`を入れている」のかと思ったのですが、
後に`for`文が続く`join`に初めて遭遇し、ググってもよく理解できませんでした。「「,」で区切って、`latest_question_list`の各要素（＝`question_text`?)ごとに`question_text`を入れている」のだとすると、`question_text`も`for q in latest_question_list`の各要素も両方`question_text`なので混乱してきます…

どなたかこのコードの意味をご教授いただけないでしょうか。

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Question

# q.question_textのオブジェクトは<Question: What's new?>の一個のみです

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)

# Leave the rest of the views (detail, results, vote) unchanged
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published2')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 1):

最新の質問を「, 」で連結しています。

```py
>>> q_list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
>>> output = ', '.join([q for q in q_list])
>>> output
'aa, bb, cc'
```

**補足**

> 後にfor文が続くjoinに初めて遭遇し、ググってもよく理解できませんでした。

このページを読むと分かると思います。

https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-comprehension/

Comment: ご回答くださりありがとうございます。
question_textとlatest_question_listの各要素は同じなので(ex.<Question: What's new?>)
output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
ではなく、
output = ', '.join(for q in latest_question_list)
でよいのではないかと思っていたのですが、このコードだと問題があるということですよね？

Comment: それだとダメ（構文エラー）ですが、`output = ', '.join(str(q) for q in latest_question_list) `であれば、同じ動きになると思います。

Comment: ちょっと説明不足だったかもしれないので、回答に補足説明のためのリンクを追記しました。また、前回のコメントにも補足しますが、`str(q)`とすることで、`__str__(self)`が呼び出されて、`self.question_text`がreturnされるので`q.question_text`と同じ結果になります。